# What merge field can we use in an email template to get the Instance needed to generate a URL to an internal knowledge article?

Tags: email-template, merge-field, refresh, instance

We are sending an email using an email template to an internal user that will have a link to an internal Knowledge article in it.

Currently I have the URL hard-coded like so:
https://na29.salesforce.com/articles/How_To_Docs/How-to-Do-This

What merge field can I use in an email template to get the Instance needed to generate a URL to an internal knowledge article?

We have an upcoming Instance Refresh so na29 will no longer be valid.

Is there a merge field I can use in place of the na29 or even in place of the na29.salesforce.com so I can recreate the URL that is needed to the Knowledge article?

*edit: I am using an email template type of Custom not Visualforce.

We are not setting up My Domain yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this we created a new Custom Setting called Global Settings with a custom field named SfdcInstanceId and then we reference the field in various locations using {!$Setup.Global_Settings__c.SfdcInstanceId__c}

Once our instance refreshes we just need to update the value in this custom field.

Answer (score 2):

There's an ancient "API version substring" hack described for example on https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096wuIAA, experiment with it a bit? If it won't work in the email template itself - you could always add the formula as a field on the article itself?

I don't have Knowledge Base handy at the moment but I'd imagine the email editor would include a proper link merge field like `{!Contact.Link}`?

Comment: I am not using a visualforce email template type.

Comment: I don't think this merge field is available in plaintext/html emails. Still - try making a formula with it on your Article, Case or whatever is the email's "master record" and then use that merge field?

Comment: This is being done in the Community welcome email.  The link that is only sent to internal users is to a Knowledge article.  I don't think a merge field would be available in this template unless I added this formula field to user which I would rather not do.